# Seeking 4-band satellite imagery?

Tags: data, classification, imagery, forest-ecology, sweden

I'm looking for good quality, fine resolution 4-band satellite photos of Sweden for academic use (and I'm willing to pay for it). What I'm after is as detailed as possible photos of certain part of Sweden where I would like to classify vegetation with commonly used indices. In order to do so I need NIR band, which is missing in the data provided by Swedish authorities. They instead offer readymade vegetation maps, which are a bit outdated for my purposes. Photos should be taken after 2005, preferably for a couple of years in different seasons.

In addition I'm looking for good quality weather data for Europe and Africa, as accurate as possible in order to evaluate the conditions birds face during migration from wintering grounds.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at the landsat data?

Comment: Use Sentinel data, it is free to download from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home

Comment: If you are seeking open data the place to ask nowadays is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

Commercial satellite imagery can be purchased either from archives or ordered as tasking for anywhere in the world through DigitalGlobe/GeoEye who have recently combined their constellation of satellites.

Imagery is usually at 50cm or 60cm.  You can actually get 8 band imagery in many cases, which would allow more specific classification.  They even have educational discounts too!